# iOS rotate video AVAsset avfoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4dFj.jpg)

Hi,

Struggling to rotate this video to show in the proper orientation and fill the entire screen.

I cannot get the avasset with videocompisition but cannot get it to work correctly.

```
    let videoAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: outputFileURL) as AVAsset

    let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first! as AVAssetTrack

    let newHeight = CGFloat(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height/3*4)

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    var videoSize = CGSize()
    videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(180, 30))

    // rotate to portrait
    let transformer:AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)
    let t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    let t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, CGFloat(M_PI_2));

    transformer.setTransform(t2, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
    let date = NSDate()
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(formatter.stringFromDate(date)).mp4"
    let outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition

    exporter.outputURL = outputURL
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.handleExportCompletion(exporter)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using. It's difficult to debug an issue if we don't know how it has been implemented.

Comment: Any ideas anyone ?  Struggling massively with this one and cannot find much at all online for this.

Comment: what is the result of the code above? could you provide a sample video that needs the rotation doing and I'll have a look later today

Comment: 2 Links one is an image of the how the video exports and one is the video itself.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8be3oqnwri4tme/IMG_0400.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iv5zot2onwqewv7/IMG_0401.mp4?dl=0   Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look soon as possible

Comment: Dropping links to images etc that are transient frustrated future readers here. For all the nuanced criticism that SO editors toss out to those who post questions, this seems ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the rotation converting from the code below:

[AVMutableVideoComposition rotated video captured in portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136841/avmutablevideocomposition-rotated-video-captured-in-portrait-mode)

Now having issues with exporting in question below if anyone knows:

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233766/avasset-failing-to-export</strike>

Comment: Anyone have actual answers to this? Seems I can't find anything in terms of just rotating a video, but I remember I used to do it with an AVAsset with rotateBy

Comment: Chewie The Chorkie, did you ever find a solution to this, I would like to rotate a video and well. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example, all you need is `(NSString *)filePath` and direction of rotation `(BOOL)isClockWise`. Processing in a background thread, you can also track progress

```
- (void)rotate:(NSString *)filePath isClockWise:(BOOL)isClockWise
{
    NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *tmpFile = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath.lastPathComponent];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tmpFile])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpFile error:nil];
    }
    
    AVAsset * asset = [ AVAsset assetWithURL:[ NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath ] ];
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL= [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpFile ];
    exporter.outputFileType = [ UTType typeWithFilenameExtension:filePath.pathExtension ].identifier;//AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.videoComposition = [ self rotateComposition:asset isClockWise:isClockWise ];
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    NSTimer * timer = [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer)
    {
        NSLog(@"%f", exporter.progress);
    } ];
    
    [ exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
    {
        void (^block)(void) = ^
        {
            if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exporter.status)
            {
                [ timer invalidate ];
                NSLog(@"success");
            }
            else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exporter.status)
            {
                [ timer invalidate ];
                NSLog(@"%@", exporter.error);
            }
        };
        
        if ([ NSThread isMainThread ])
        {
            block();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
        }
    } ];
}

- (AVVideoComposition *)rotateComposition:(AVAsset *)asset isClockWise:(BOOL)isClockWise
{
    AVMutableVideoComposition * result = [ AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset ];
    
    NSMutableArray * instructionArray = [ NSMutableArray array ];
    for (AVAssetTrack * track in [ asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo ])
    {
        CGAffineTransform oldTransform = track.preferredTransform;
        CGSize oldSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
        oldSize = CGSizeMake(ABS(oldSize.width), ABS(oldSize.height));
        
        CGAffineTransform newTransform;
        if (isClockWise) 
        {
            CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0 * M_PI / 180.0);
            CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(oldSize.height, 0.0);
            newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter);
            newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(oldTransform, newTransform);
        } 
        else
        {
            CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90.0 * M_PI / 180.0);
            CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, oldSize.width);
            newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter);
            newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(oldTransform, newTransform);
        }
        
        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction * layerInstructions = [ AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:track ];
        [ layerInstructions setTransform:newTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero ];
        
        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * instruction = [ AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction ];
        instruction.timeRange = track.timeRange;
        instruction.layerInstructions = [ NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstructions ];
        
        [ instructionArray addObject:instruction ];
    }
    result.instructions = instructionArray;
    result.renderSize = CGSizeMake(result.renderSize.height, result.renderSize.width);
    
    return result;
}
```