# How do I put video A on top of video B? About merge videos on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, video, merge, gpuimage

I want to merge two videos, it look likes:

- Video A:
  [image]
- Video B:
  [image]
- Last video:
  [image]

This is a very interesting deal, you could try this on app named [SHOOT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1181310214).I want to implement a similar effect, but how? Can [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) or [AVAnimator](https://github.com/mdejong/AVAnimator) help me implement it?

I had try GPUImage like this:

```
let movieURL = URL(
    string: "sample_iPod.m4v",
    relativeTo: Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    )!
let specialMovieURL = URL(
    string: "cartoon_watermark.mov",
    relativeTo: Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    )!
let writerURL = URL(
    fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("last.mov")
)
print("Writer URL: \(writerURL)")

do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: writerURL)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

self.movie = GPUImageMovie(url: movieURL)
self.movie.delegate = self
self.movie.playAtActualSpeed = true

self.specialMovie = GPUImageMovie(url: specialMovieURL)
self.specialMovie.playAtActualSpeed = true

self.filter = GPUImageScreenBlendFilter()

self.movie.addTarget(self.filter)
self.specialMovie.addTarget(self.filter)
self.filter.addTarget(self.renderView)

self.movie.startProcessing()
self.specialMovie.startProcessing()
```

It didn't works...Or if I could use AVFoundationKit to get it done?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: look at these links https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859872/how-to-merge-multiple-videos-using-avasset-in-ios

I have never used them but should be useful for you.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Thank you but this post couldn't help me in this case...

Comment: See the Fireworks example app on the AVAnimator page, it shows how to overlay one video on top of 1 to N other videos.