# I am uploading video to server after merging it with other video but the recorded video is rotated clockwise

Tags: ios, objective-c

Merging Code-

> AVAsset *firstAsset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:urlIntroVideo]; AVAsset
>   *secondAsset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:recordedVideoUrl];
>
> if (firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil) {
>       //[[AppDelegate Getdelegate] showIndicator];
>       // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
>       AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
>       // 2 - Video track
>
> ```
> /********************************************************************************
>
>  --------------->>      VIDEO MERGING TRACK              <<--------------------
>
>  ********************************************************************************/
>
>
>
> AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
>                                                                     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
>
> NSArray *videoTracks = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]];
> NSLog(@"Video Tracks count  1st Assest=> %ld",[videoTracks count]);
>
>
> NSArray *audioTracks = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]];
> NSLog(@"Auido Tracks count => %ld",[audioTracks count]);
>
>
>
> [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
>                     ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
> ```
>
> atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
>
> ```
> [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
>                     ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
> ```
>
> atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];
>
> NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
>
> ```
> NSString *potrait_intro = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"silent08s.mp3"];
>
> NSURL    *potrait_intro_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:potrait_intro];
>
>
> AVAsset *audioAssest=[AVAsset assetWithURL:potrait_intro_url];
>
>
> AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
> ```
>
> preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
>
> ```
> NSArray *audioTracksSilent = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [audioAssest tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]];
>
>
> [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAssest.duration)
>                     ofTrack:([audioTracksSilent count]>0)?[audioTracksSilent objectAtIndex:0]:nil
>                      atTime:kCMTimeZero
>                       error:nil];
>
>
>
> NSArray *audioTracks2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]];
> NSLog(@"Auido Tracks count => %ld",[audioTracks2 count]);
>
> [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
>                     ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
>                      atTime:audioAssest.duration
>                       error:nil];
>
> //
>
>
>
> //  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
> NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
>                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
> NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString
> ```
>
> stringWithFormat:@"final_merged_video-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
>
> ```
> NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
> // 5 - Create exporter
> AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
>                                                                   presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
> exporter.outputURL=url;
> exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
> exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
> [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
>     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>
>         [[AppDelegate Getdelegate] hideIndicator];
>
>         [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
>     });
> }]; }
> ```

Please help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

You probably loose the rotation info on your AVAsset when you merged both videos and/or your server is unable to process it.
What you need to do is getting the rotation info (you can use this for example : https://gist.github.com/lukabernardi/5020724 ), and then rotate the video accordingly BEFORE sending it to the server.

Comment: thanx for your answer it helps me getting the orientation but now how to rotate that AVasset by 90 degree?

Comment: You can follow this answer to help fix your issue :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136841/avmutablevideocomposition-rotated-video-captured-in-portrait-mode

Comment: It doesnt woked!! After merging two videos the recorded one  is rotated by 90 degree and other one's orientation is fine

Comment: You need to be more specific about your issue

Comment: I am merging two videos in potrait mode.The first video is a normal mp4 video in potrait video and other one is the video which i am recording fron my camera in potrait from.Now when i merge both video the first video orientation is fine but the second video is rotated by 90 degree

Comment: You are not specific.
At which point did you transform the video?
Why one did you transform?
Is this your original issue or what is happening after your latest tries?