# Rotate recorded video by 90 degree programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have recorded a video in iphone and I am getting its local file URL. Is there any way to rotate that video by 90 degree using the URL?

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik  i am not getting any idea how to do it

Comment: how do u load ur video it s AVplayer  or MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: i have to merge it with other video and send it to server

Comment: Why do you want to rotate to 90 degree? is your recorded video coming rotated?

Comment: @iphonic because i am merging it with other video and uploading to server the recorded video gets rotated by 90 degree.So i thought to send the rotated video so that it may again rotate and should get me the right orientation

Comment: Add your whole code how you are merging and creating video, problem is there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504966/i-am-uploading-video-to-server-after-merging-it-with-other-video-but-the-recorde/42505363?noredirect=1#comment72193285_42505363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate the Video before exporting session using `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` class and you can apply `Transform`  on it .

This is the method

```
 [yourlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2) atTime:firstAssets.duration];
```

here is the full implementation

```
          AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

          AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];


          AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration));

          AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *firstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction 
    videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack]; 

// set Trasform Here 
  [firstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

       [firstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];

          mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstlayerInstruction,nil];;

         AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

         mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
            mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
            mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

         AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                              presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
            exporter.outputURL=url;
            exporter.videoComposition=mainCompositionInst;
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
            exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
            [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
                });
            }];
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score -2):

If you are using MPMoviePlayerViewController for playing video:-
Then you can try this,
First fetch your url from bundle using below line,

```
  NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
```

Or you can use your local file url directly in mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Then create MPmovieplayerview controller's object and use your video file as shown below :-

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well this will just rotate the video while playing, he wants it to rotate while exporting and sending the video to server.