# AVMutableComposition - Portrait video gets landscaped

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, avasset

I have used the following code to merge multiple videos to one.

```
func mergeMultipleVideos() {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    var time: Double = 0.0

    for video in self.arrayOfSelectedVideoURL {
        let sourceAsset = AVAsset(url: video as URL)
        let videoAssetTrack = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        let audioAssetTrack = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
        let atTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale:1)

        do{
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration) , of: videoAssetTrack, at: atTime)
            try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration) , of: audioAssetTrack, at: atTime)
        }catch{
            print("-----Something wrong.")
        }
        time +=  sourceAsset.duration.seconds
    }

    mergeVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/mergeVideo.mp4")
    let exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter.outputURL = mergeVideoURL as URL
    exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
        {
            switch exporter.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(exporter.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(exporter.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(exporter.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(exporter.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(exporter.error)")
            default:
                print("-----Merge video exportation complete.\(self.mergeVideoURL)")
            }
    })
}
```

the above done the job. But the problem is, if I select a portrait video, it gets landscaped in the final exported video. I need to keep the actual orientation all videos in my final video.
I have tried with these code snippets

> ```
>         //video orientation
>         let assetVideoTrack = (sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)).last
>         let compositionVideoTrack = (composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)).last
>         if ((assetVideoTrack?.isPlayable)! && (compositionVideoTrack?.isPlayable)!) {
>             compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = (assetVideoTrack?.preferredTransform)!
>         }
> ```

from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136841/avmutablevideocomposition-rotated-video-captured-in-portrait-mode) . It didn't work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: but I am not getting the expected result....can you help please ?

Comment: if any one still having this issue you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/71109215/9963757